# Perform chisq or fisher test on grouped data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in which I want to perform a fisher's exact test within groups. For example,

```
df <- data.frame(
  grouping = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), each = 2),
  factor = rep(c('healthy', 'sick'), 4), 
  increase = sample(1:10, 8, replace = T),
  decrease = sample(0:10, 8, replace = T))
```

For each 'grouping' variable, I want a p-value for Fisher's exact test comparing the 'increase' and 'decrease' columns for each factor of healthy vs sick. How can I format this, and create a new column for each p-value? My resulting data frame should be 4 rows summarizing the 'grouping' column and fisher test p-value?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple loop can do the trick:

```
output<-lapply(unique(df$grouping), function(letter){
  testdf<-df[df$grouping==letter,]
  pvalue<-fisher.test(testdf[,c("increase", "decrease")])$p
  out<-data.frame(letter, pvalue)
})

do.call(rbind, output)

#  letter     pvalue
#1      a 0.67276888
#2      b 0.02941176
#3      c 0.04076367
#4      d 0.41971014
```

If there are multiple grouping columns then create a new column by pasting together the grouping columns and use the routine above or use the dplyr package to perform the multiple groupings:

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>% group_by(grouping, grouping2) %>%
   summarize(pvalue=fisher.test(matrix(c(increase, decrease), nrow =2))$p)
```

Comment: Actually I realized in my real data I have two grouping variables. If they were called grouping1 and grouping2, how could I modify your response to account for both?